# Darlington transistor on in/out pin of Arduino

Tags: arduino, transistors

I’m designing a PCB for my home cockpit and I want some flexibilty. In general I will use the D2 pin of an Arduino as an output to drive a Darlington transistor for panel backlighting, but I want this to be optional and retain the input option of the D2 pin for places where I don’t need backlight, but more inputs.

Do I need a switch between the D2 pin and the transistor or can I simply leave the backlight unconnected from the transistor and use the D2 pin as input that way?

This will potentionally apply a voltage to the Darlington transistor, but will this have any negative impact as long as the transiator has nothing connected to it?

Comment: As long as the base resistor to the Darlington is large enough to avoid adversely loading whatever you might want to drive the D2 input from it'll be fine to leave it connected.

Comment: Consider the worst case scenario, you make a mistake and where you intended a Darlington load you have another input source instead.  If you connect a Darlington to a mcu pin configured as input, it won't work, but no damage. If you connect another output device to a pin configured as output, there is a chance of a short circuit that may damage the input device or the MCU  If your application can tolerate a series resistance this could limit the short circuit current in the worst case scenario (output to output) or if the input source is high impedance then the risk is already low..

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about something like this (the RH diagram is a commercial Darlington pair and includes the resistors shown):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffnapw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you try to use either as an input by connecting directly to the GPIO you'll have loading on the input. If it's driven by a logic gate with push-pull output there will be no problem.

On the other hand, if you're connecting it to a switch with a pull-up or pull-down then the loading could have an adverse effect.

Comment: Thanks for answering, what does push-pull mean? I would be connecting a simple SPST switch to it and using the built-in pull-up resistor in the Arduino.

Comment: Push-pull means an output driver that can both source and sink the current. GPIO outputs are typically push-pull unless they are configured otherwise (e.g. open collector/open drain).

Comment: The pull-up resistor in the Arduino will be too weak to generate a “high” with the switch open. You could add an external pull down resistor and connect the switch between Vdd and the input.